# Mono - Uri class

Tags: c#, .net, mono, httpwebrequest

I am making an HttpWebRequest at a url similar to this:

```
"http://mysite.com/search?query=my+search+string"
```

Problem is, the Uri class escapes it with %, and the site I'm making the request against can't handle the escaped characters.  (I have no control to fix the site)

So tried this [Obsolete] constructor:

```
new Uri(myUriString, true);
```

But it did not seem to make any difference, when debugging, my Uri still got escaped.

I am running this on a Mac with Mono, but I have not tried it on standard .Net on Windows to see if it has the same behavior.

Is there another way to get around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://mysite.com/search?query=my+search+string");
Console.WriteLine(uri.ToString());
```

through Microsoft .NET Runtime and Mono on a Windows 7 machine and it did not escape the characters. Are you sure this URL isn't getting appended to another url where it thinks this is a query parameter?

Comment: Send it through HttpWebRequest.Create and look at the resulting RequestUri.  (And maybe don't call ToString, look in the Uri object while debugging)  If you still see this, it may be the version of Mono on the Mac.

Comment: @Jonathan I'm replying to you on my Mac now. I ran the same tests, even with HttpWebRequest.Create() and I cannot get it to do what you are saying. Can you post a complete code example that you claim fails and the output of it? I am using mono 2.8.2 on OS X 10.5.7. I really have a feeling that you are not putting what you think you are as the Uri string. Please check your example and make sure it exactly replicates what you are using. If the site is not sensitive post the actual URI. You can change the domain name if need be.

Comment: Good insight, sir.  I was actually calling HttpUtility.UrlEncode on my search string, so there was no issue with the Uri class, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I don't see a way around this. Escaping characters via hexcodes is in the Uri spec and should be adhered by the server.